# Can a GitLab runner be given access rights to an AWS account?

Tags: amazon-web-services, gitlab

To DevOps,
I am running a GitLab pipeline and I want to push a created image to an AWS ECR in an account. How would I give access rights to the GitLab Runner to access the AWS ECR?
Thanks,
Marc

Comment: See if this helps: https://mrkaran.dev/posts/gitlab-runner-ecr/

Comment: You just need to give the runner an IAM role with the required permissions